# Surfing etiquette when catching a wave

Tags: surfing, etiquette

I'm a beginner surfer. Here's a video from my most recent lesson (13th lesson in the last 16 months) the other day in Lima, Peru.

https://youtu.be/4FaWUseaW6A

A few seconds in another surfer to my left drops in. Since he was further inside does he have the right-of-way? Or because I caught the wave first do I have the right-of-way?

He's obviously way more experienced than me. I was kinda surprised he caught the wave since I was already on it. Maybe he was hoping/expecting me to fall so he could have it to himself?

Feel free to critique any technique as well, I'm just trying to learn all things surfing!!

Comment: I am not a surfer, so my comment may not be to the point.  First, I'm not sure who you are and who the interloping surfer is.  You said, "surfer to my left", that looks like the surfer who fell off his board (or who aborted his ride.)  Call him X.  On general courtesy terms, X came too close to you, but then redeemed himself by aborting.  OTOH, If the surfer who fell off his board (aborted?) was YOU, then you were perhaps  cutting things too fine, whether on a surfboard, or on a bike, or ice-skating or pushing a shopping cart.  But, hey, we all have to learn.

Comment: I was the one who didn't abort and continued to ride. From the video it looks like he had *way* more control than me, and bailed intentionally. Still not clear if I should have been the one to get out of *his* way.